# Question about majorization of eigenvalues after conjugation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, eigenvalues

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ positive semidefinite matrices with eigenvalues $\alpha_1 \ge \alpha_2 \ge \ldots \ge \alpha_n$ and $\beta_1 \ge \beta_2 \ge \ldots \ge \beta_n$ respectively. Furthermore, let $\gamma_1 \ge \gamma_2 \ge \ldots \ge \gamma_n$ be the eigenvalues of $BAB^\dagger$. Is it true that the vector $(\alpha_1\beta^2_1, \alpha_2\beta^2_2, \ldots, \alpha_n\beta^2_n)$ weakly majorizes the vector $(\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \ldots, \gamma_n)$, i.e. that

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i\beta^2_i \ge \sum_{j=1}^k \gamma_j
\end{equation}

for $1 \le k \le n$?

Comment: Am i right it's enough in fact to check this conjecture for elementary matrices $B$?

Comment: Obviously, your question comes from studies of spectra of graphs -- please tell us the corresponding graph story, where this problem appears there!

Comment: @Victor Actually this is not related to a graph theory problem, but a problem in quantum information.

Comment: Ok, i thought in the lines of Cvetkovic's book